# How to :use (or :require) a custom file in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, sublimetext, sublimerepl

Super beginner question here. I'm following the (good) book *Programming Clojure*, and chapter 5 is about coding a small Snake game. Utility code is provided, and I decided to follow it by starting a new *Leiningen* project (`lein new app snake`). In my `src/snake/core.clj` I'd like to `:use` a file named `import_static.clj` written by the authors. I copied the file into `src/snake`, and in `src/snake/core.clj` I copied from the samples the import line `(:use snake.import-static)`. But when I evalute the whole file in the REPL I have this error : "FileNotFoundException Could not locate import_static__init.class or import_static.clj on classpath".

Using Clojure 1.5.1, both in the `project.clj` file and the editor's REPL (SublimeText + plugin SublimeREPL). The directory structure :

```
src/
  snake/
    core.clj
    import_static.clj
```

Top of `core.clj` :

```
(ns snake.core
    (:import (java.awt Color Dimension)
       (javax.swing JPanel JFrame Timer JOptionPane)
           (java.awt.event ActionListener KeyListener))
  (:gen-class)
  (:use snake.import-static))
```

Top of `import_static.clj` :

```
(ns ^{:author "Stuart Sierra",
      :doc "Import static Java methods/fields into Clojure"}
  snake.import-static
  (:use clojure.set))
```

I tried removing the `snake` from both the `:use` call and the namespace declaration, with no luck. Can you help me ? Note that I have no knowledge of the JVM, and it may be the classpath or my editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out, and thought I would share the answer with everyone.

It had nothing to do with the code, but my editor's REPL. Lein's REPL was ok as I could run `lein run` and `lein repl` and see the prompt being set to the namespace `snake.core=>`, whereas in SublimeText's SublimeREPL's REPL it was set to `user.core=>`. I just had to close it, open the `project.clj` file and from here open launch a Clojure REPL with SublimeREPL. It is now set properly to `snake.core=>` and no more error.

Back to coding !

Comment: It is expected that a repl to put you into the user ns when you start it (though not user.core, I have never seen that). You can switch to an ns as follows `(in-ns 'snake.core)`, after requiring the file that defines it.

Comment: Didn't know about the `in-ns` function, thanks for the pointer.